# App starting and closing instantly - CustomSwipeAdapter - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-imageview

[image]

The app is getting built successfully in android studio but the app is not displayed in emulator.  I am trying to display two images, one image at a time. And swipe will take the user on to next image. Not sure what's going wrong.

I could have done a silly mistake, as I am a complete beginner.

Custom swipe adapter Java screenshot:

[image: custom swipe adapter Java screenshot]

Comment: Pls let me know in case you need any other screenshot or code from my project for investigation

Comment: show your code...

Comment: It could be `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {<br/>

    ViewPager viewPager;<br/>
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;<br/>

    @Override<br/>
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {<br/>
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);<br/>
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);<br/>
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);<br/>
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this);<br/>
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);<br/>
    }<br/>
}<br/>

Comment: package com.example.home.foodmenu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}

Comment: ^ Please delete the code from the comments. When someone asks to see your code, then mean that they'd like you to add the code into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance of memory leakage (check your log getting exception like this `OutOfMemoryException`)
You can read this post `http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html`
cause of memory leakage.

for quick fix you can add
android:largeHeap="true" in your manifest application tag

Comment: please find out the error from the log file, connect your device with AS when you are getting close your application see the log file , there you will be get some error please check what are you getting